# How to Create and Render Basic Template in Golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How to Create and Render Basic Template in Golang?
       - Create Login Form
       - Save that in UserLogin struct (datastore.put and also datastore.get)

```
    type UserLogin struct{
         UserName string
         PassWord string
     }
```

I was Created following example from some document from google:
But this was created with the default user available in Go-app.
Want to create Open Id login form with Go. 
How to do this?

```
package hello

import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"   
    "html/template"
    "net/http"       
)    
//AdminData Structure
type AdminData struct {
    UserName  string
    UserPassword string    
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)  
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
}    

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("AdminData").Limit(10)
    adminsdata := make([]AdminData, 0, 10)
    if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &adminsdata); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    if err := loginTemplate.Execute(w, adminsdata); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

var loginTemplate = template.Must(template.New("book").Parse(loginTemplateHTML))

const loginTemplateHTML = `
<html>
  <body>
    {{range .}}
      {{with .UserName}}
        <p><b>{{.}}</b> user name:</p>
      {{else}}
        <p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
      {{end}}
      <pre>{{.UserPassword}}</b> password:</p></pre>
    {{end}}
    <form action="/login" method="post">     
      <div>User Name : <input type="text" name="userName" value=""> </div>
      <div>Password : <input type="password" name="userPassword" value=""> </div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
`

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    g := AdminData{
        UserName : r.FormValue("userName"),enter code here
        UserPassword : r.FormValue("userPassword"),
    }

    _, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "AdminData", nil), &g)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
}
```

Comment: with google or with other providers ?

Comment: Question far too broad to answer.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : Above is the Example for reference. How to create a User login Form with Go Programming ?

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO : With Google app engine.

Answer (score 2):

in you google appengine console change in basic settings the auth, to openid provider

then add the following code, it checks if an appengine user is logged in, if not he will show him the google login page.

```
u := user.Current(c)
if u == nil {
    url, err := user.LoginURL(c, r.URL.String())
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Location", url)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
    return
}
```